# Using the C++ atomic lib, what memory order(s) should I use for a load followed by a compare exchange?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

For example, with multiple threads executing the update() function:

```
// Statically allocated
atomic<int> high_water{0};
//...
void update(int meas)
{
int i;
bool replaced;
do
{
i = high_water.load(?);
if (i >= meas)
  break;
replaced = high_water.compare_exchange_strong(i, meas, ?, ?);
}
while (!replaced);
// ...
```

(I am trying to implement a shared high water mark of individual measurements taken in multiple threads.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compare_exchange_strong` is atomic with respect to `high_water`, no matter what memory order you specify to it. Memory ordering only matters with respect to *other* memory operations. It largely depends on how and when other threads need to see `high_water`. Since `meas` is only visible in this thread, so there are no other loads and stores to consider. Thus, `memory_order_relaxed` is correct.

---

As a secondary note, `compare_exchange_strong` replaces the first parameter with the observed value, so performing that `load` is redundant.

```
int i = high_water.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
while (i < meas
      && high_water.compare_exchange_strong(i,
                                            meas,
                                            std::memory_order_relaxed,
                                            std::memory_order_relaxed
                                           )
      )
    continue;
```

Comment: `while ( i < meas && ! high_water.compare_exchange_strong(…) ) ;`

Answer (score 2):

> what memory order(s) should I use for a load followed by a compare exchange?

It is impossible to tell because you don't show the code where `update()` is called.
Reordering of memory operations surrounding that call is a real thing on certain platforms if you use `memory_order_relaxed` (or anything weaker than the default for that matter).
`high_water` may actually be used to synchronize data between threads. *If* you are not worried about those possible reorderings, then `std::memory_order_relaxed` is fine.

Generally, for these kinds of operations, I would not use a weaker ordering than the default (`std::memory_order_seq_cst`).
Since `std::compare_exchange_strong` is a Read-Modify-Write (RMW) operation, which by definition is expensive because it synchronizes the value of the atomic between cores,
changing memory ordering is not going to be much of an advantage. At least on X86, with your code, the compiiler will emit the exact same object code for `std::memory_order_seq_cst` and `std::memory_order_relaxed`.

Side note, since you are in a loop, you may want to use `compare_exchange_weak()`, which may fail spuriously, but that is handled by the loop.